# Replace strings in multiple files with corresponding caps using bash on MacOSX

Tags: macos, bash, awk, sed

I have multiple .txt files, in which I want to replace the strings

```
old -> new
Old -> New
OLD -> NEW
```

The first step is to only replace one string Old->New. Here is my current code, but it does not do the job (the files remain unchanged). The sed line works only if I replace the variables with the actual strings.

```
#!/bin/bash 
old_string="Old"
new_string="New"
sed -i '.bak' 's/$old_string/$new_string/g' *.txt
```

Also, how do I convert a string to all upper-caps and all lower-caps?

Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: You might be better off using `perl`.  Refer to `perldoc perlfaq6`: _How do I substitute case-insensitively on the LHS while preserving case on the RHS?_

Comment: @devnull: The Perl script you reference is powerful, but its matching is more permissive than what this question asks for - which may or may not be desired: since it performs case-insensitive _matching_, strings such as `oLd` would be matched, too, and would be replaced with `nEw`.

Comment: Are the strings always separated by spaces (x old y) or can they be separated by other chars (x old-ish y)? Can they be part of other strings (e.g. should "smolder" become "smnewer")? Can they contain RE metacharacters or are they always alphabetic or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @merlin2011's helpful answer:

If you wanted to create the case variants *dynamically*, try this:

```
# Define search and replacement strings
# as all-lowercase.
old_string='old'
new_string='new'

# Loop 3 times and create the case variants dynamically.
# Build up a _single_ sed command that performs all 3 
# replacements.
sedCmd=
for (( i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )); do    
  case $i in
    1)  # as defined (all-lowercase)
      old_string_variant=$old_string
      new_string_variant=$new_string
      ;;
    2) # initial capital
      old_string_variant="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${old_string:0:1}")${old_string:1}"
      new_string_variant="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${new_string:0:1}")${new_string:1}"
      ;;
    3) # all-uppercase
      old_string_variant=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$old_string")
      new_string_variant=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$new_string")
      ;;
  esac
  # Append to the sed command string. Note the use of _double_ quotes
  # to ensure that variable references are expanded.         
  sedCmd+="s/$old_string_variant/$new_string_variant/g; "
done

# Finally, invoke sed.
sed -i '.bak' "$sedCmd" *.txt
```

Note that `bash 4` supports case conversions directly (as part of parameter expansion), but OS X, as of 10.9.3, is still on `bash 3.2.51`.

---

**Alternative solution**, using `awk` to create the case variants and synthesize the `sed` command:

Aside from being shorter, it is also **more robust**, because it also handles strings correctly that happen to contain characters that are regex metacharacters (characters with special meaning in an regular expression, e.g., `*`) or have special meaning in `sed`'s `s` function's replacement-string parameter (e.g., `\`), through appropriate escaping; without escaping, the `sed` command would not work as expected.
*Caveat*: Doesn't support strings with embedded `\n` chars. (though that could be fixed, too).

```
# Define search and replacement strings as all-lowercase literals.
old_string='old'
new_string='new'

# Synthesize the sed command string, utilizing awk and its tolower() and toupper()
# functions to create the case variants.
#   Note the need to escape \ chars to prevent awk from interpreting them.
sedCmd=$(awk \
  -v old_string="${old_string//\\/\\\\}" \
  -v new_string="${new_string//\\/\\\\}" \
  'BEGIN {
    printf "s/%s/%s/g; s/%s/%s/g; s/%s/%s/g", 
      old_string, new_string, 
      toupper(substr(old_string,1,1)) substr(old_string,2), toupper(substr(new_string,1,1)) substr(new_string,2), 
      toupper(old_string), toupper(new_string)
  }')

# Invoke sed with the synthesized command.
#   The inner sed command ensures that all regex metacharacters in the strings 
#   are escaped so that sed treats them as literals.
sed -i '.bak' "$(sed 's#[][(){}^$.*?+\]#\\&#g' <<<"$sedCmd")" *.txt
```

Comment: +1. I am amazed that you decided to do this in `bash`, so props to you. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 Thank you; it is a fairly cumbersome solution, so I agree that looking for more powerful tools is worthwhile.

Comment: Your loop is not exactly necessary—I would actually say it makes things more complicated than to just do the stuff sequentially.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf To me the loop helps to make what's going on _conceptually clearer_, but I agree that it's not an elegant solution overall; have a look at the `awk`-assisted alternative that I just posted, which makes do without a loop (and is also more robust thanks to escaping).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do `bash` variable expansion inside the argument to `sed`, you need to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`.

```
sed -i '.bak' "s/$old_string/$new_string/g" *.txt
```

In terms of getting matches on all three of the literal substitutions, the cleanest solution may be just to run `sed` three times in a loop like this.

```
declare -a olds=(old Old OLD)
declare -a news=(new New NEW)

for i in `seq 0 2`; do 
 sed  -i "s/${olds[$i]}/${news[$i]}/g" *.txt
done;
```

**Update**: The solution above works on Linux, but apparently `OS X` has different requirements. Additionally, as @mklement0 mentioned, my `for` loop is silly. Here is an improved version for `OS X`.

```
declare -a olds=(old Old OLD)
declare -a news=(new New NEW)

for (( i = 0; i < ${#olds[@]}; i++ )); do
 sed  -i '.bak' "s/${olds[$i]}/${news[$i]}/g" *.txt
done;
```

Comment: Thanks merlin, that works for replacing "Old" with "New".
However, I also want to convert the other cases without having to define 6 variables. (I have a ton of words to replace).

Can I convert the old_string variable to all-upper-caps somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: +1, but OSX `sed` requires `-i ''` (note the required space) to modify in-place without creating a backup file (2nd snippet); also, `for i in $(seq 0 2)` hurts a little; can I suggest `for (( i = 0; i < ${#olds[@]}; i++ ))`?

Comment: @mklement0, Thank you. I will make the edits. I do not have access so OSX, so I will take your suggestions on faith. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update; actually, that should be `''` not `' '` to suppress creating a backup file (sorry - by "required space" I meant you need the space _between_ `-i` and the empty string, `''`). But you could just stick with `-i '.bak'`, as your first snippet, which works on OSX too.

Comment: @user2926577, If you are trying to make it a case-insensitive match, you can add the `/I` flag to the end of the `s` command. If you want want to somehow *copy the case* while replacing `OLd` with `NEw` for example, then I think you'll have to use a more powerful tool.

Comment: @merlin2011: Sorry to the be the wet OSX blanket again, but the `s` command's `I` flag - a GNU `sed` extension - is not available in OSX (FreeBSD) `sed`.

Comment: @mklement0, I appreciate it. It is exactly users like you who keep the quality high and the answers very specific to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each string is separated by spaces from your other strings and that you don't want partial matches within longer strings and that you don't care about preserving white space on output and assuming that if an "old" string matches on a "new" string after a previous conversion operation, then the string should be changed again:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(tolower(old),oldStrs)
    split(tolower(new),newStrs)
}
{
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {

        for (stringNr=1; stringNr in oldStrs; stringNr++) {

            oldStr = oldStrs[stringNr]

            if (tolower($fldNr) == oldStr) {

                newStr = newStrs[stringNr]
                split(newStr,newChars,"")

                split($fldNr,fldChars,"")
                $fldNr = ""

                for (charNr=1; charNr in fldChars; charNr++) {

                    fldChar = fldChars[charNr]
                    newChar = newChars[charNr]

                    $fldNr = $fldNr ( fldChar ~ /[[:lower:]]/ ?
                                      newChar : toupper(newChar) )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
The old Old OLD smOLDering QuICk brown FoX jumped

$ awk -v old="old" -v new="new" -f tst.awk file
The new New NEW smOLDering QuICk brown FoX jumped
```

Note that the "old" in "smOLDering" did not get changed. Is that desirable?

```
$ awk -v old="QUIck Fox" -v new="raBid DOG" -f tst.awk file
The old Old OLD smOLDering RaBId brown DoG jumped

$ awk -v old="THE brown Jumped" -v new="FEW dingy TuRnEd" -f tst.awk file
Few old Old OLD smOLDering QuICk dingy FoX turned
```

Think about whether or not this is your expected output:

```
$ awk -v old="old new" -v new="new yes" -f tst.awk file
The yes Yes YES smOLDering QuICk brown FoX jumped
```

A few lines of sample input and expected output in the question would be useful to avoid all the guessing and assumptions.